# fetch record and create new record with modification

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Using python, psychopg2 trying to figure out how to fetch a record and create a new record with a modification from said record. I have everything working, connection, creating new records. I'm stuck on the point of modifying the fetched record.

newrecord=cursor.fetchone()

and I'm stuck now with the next move. How do I identify the column so I can modify it. Table is a simple table with id and a true/false column. Seems like a simple task.

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres", 
password = "secret", database = "example")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table3;')

cursor.execute ('''
CREATE TABLE table3 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
''')

data0 = {
    'id': 1,
    'completed': True
}
data = {
    'id': 2,
    'completed': False
}
data2 = {
    'id': 3,
    'completed': False
}
data3 = {
    'id': 4,
    'completed': True
}
data4 = {
    'id': 5,
    'completed': True
}
SQL = 'INSERT INTO table3 (id,completed) values (%(id)s, %(completed)s);'

cursor.execute (SQL, data0)
cursor.execute (SQL, data)
cursor.execute (SQL, data2)
cursor.execute (SQL, data3)
cursor.execute (SQL, data4)

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table3;')
newrecord = cursor.fetchone()


print(newrecord)
# cursor.execute(SQL, newrecord)
# result = cursor.fetchall()
# for row in result:
#     print (row)

connection.commit()

connection.close()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: `UPDATE table2 SET completed = %s WHERE id = %s`?

Comment: the task is to grab a record, and create a new record based on the fetched record however modified. Not an update but create a new based on fetched record.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is quite unclear, which problem you are facing - I am trying to answer.
You could `INSERT` from a `SELECT` to prevent fetching and 'resending' the record to the database:

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mf port=5959 host=localhost user=mf_usr")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table3;')

cursor.execute ('''
CREATE TABLE table3 (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    price INT,
    completed BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
''')

data0 = {
    'id': 1,
    'completed': True
}
data = {
    'id': 2,
    'completed': False
}
data2 = {
    'id': 3,
    'completed': False
}
data3 = {
    'id': 4,
    'completed': True
}
data4 = {
    'id': 5,
    'completed': True
}

# Insert 5 rows
SQL = 'INSERT INTO table3 (id,name,price,completed) values (%(id)s, %(name)s, %(price)s, %(completed)s);'
for i in range(0, 5):
    cursor.execute (SQL, {'id': i, 'price': (i+1)*1000, 'name': f"data_{i}", 'completed': True})


# COPY a record, just modifying id and completed.
COPY_SQL = """
    INSERT INTO table3 (id, name, price, completed)
    (SELECT %(id)s, name, price, %(completed)s from table3 where name=%(name)s)
"""

COPY_VALUES = {'id': 6, 'name': 'data_0', 'completed': False}
cursor.execute(COPY_SQL, COPY_VALUES)

# FETCH: We end up with 2 records for data_n with completed True and False!
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table3 where name = '%(name)s'" % COPY_VALUES)
print(cursor.fetchall())

connection.commit()
connection.close()
cursor.close()
```

Out:

```
[(0, 'data_0', 1000, True), (6, 'data_0', 1000, False)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Not quite I was looking for but this works. Thank you.